# Elasticsearch combine queries when searching via a child or parent

Tags: elasticsearch

I am very new to Elasticsearch, and have tried my best to find an answer for my question both via the docs, Google and most importantly here.

Currently, I am having to separate my queries via children or parents to find what I am looking for. This is what I have right now (I am using a Kibana module called Sense for my cURL requests):

```
GET /raow/raower/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "break",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "smoke": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "break",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "time": "12:00"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, my two queries on has_child both look through the child of raower which is break for a match, but I am struggling to combine the two. Any help would be most appreciated. As I said before I am very new to Elasticsearch, so if anything else about the syntax would be better to change by all means tell me!

Seeing as this is my first question I really hope it hasn't been asked before, I did my best to find it so if it may have been asked before my apologies.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Thomas! I did not understand your question clearly. What do you mean by "combine the two"? What is the result that you are expecting and what are you getting instead? Also please mention the mapping definition of `raower` and `break`. That information might come in handy.

Comment: What I meant by combining the two was a cleaner way of getting a result by more than one match for a child or parent. Basically cleaner code, Brooke B (the approved) provided a great answer. Sorry for being off for a while, I was a bit occupied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `has_child` accepts any query, perhaps it would work for you to simply nest the `bool` query inside your `has_child` query. For example:

```
GET /raow/raower/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "break",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "smoke": false
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "time": "12:00"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, this looks far better and cleaner than my old method.